# mono update - ca-certificates-mono - available 240 looking for 268

Tags: 14.04, apt, mono

There has been some time that mono would not update. The problem is that this message stops other updates so even if I try to remove mono-develop I am failing.

apt-get says:

```
mono-devel : Depends: ca-certificates-mono (= 5.18.0.268-0xamarin7+ubuntu1404b1) but 5.18.0.240-0xamarin1+ubuntu1404b1 is installed
```

tried different recipes I could found around. Nothing worked. Official mono installation site https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/

says:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

and this is the point I get above dependancy message. If that was only related to mono not being unable to update it would be fine but this error jeopardize other regular apt-get updates.

Any hints how to overcome this situation? Perhaps the way how to go to previous working version?

Comment: `sudo aptitude -f remove mono-runtime` removed mono from updates for the time being so that I can do updates to other packages.

Comment: and after update of other packages, mono installs with no issues.
    `mono --version`
    
`Mono JIT compiler version 5.18.0.268 (tarball Thu Feb 28 15:28:45 UTC 2019)`

Answer (score 0):

Original aim was not to be blocked to do updates of other packages.

Luckily I had installation of `aptitude` already (perhaps legacy of having another type of problems earlier). Recommendation: have aptitude installed even if you do not need it right now (while you can - that is).

Aptitude hint comes from some other unrelated question here on Ask Ubuntu.

so...

Step1: remove mono

```
sudo aptitude -f remove mono-runtime
```

this removes mono (and some related packages)

Step2: update the rest of the system (whatever method you need to employ) in my case I have did some `sudo apt-get update` some `sudo apt-get autoremove` and some additional (unrelated) cleanups and upgrades.

Step3: Go back to https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ and follow steps to install mono for my version (14.04). Interestingly - no complains - everything went smooth as it has never been a problem before (not even ca-certificates-mono that was causing the problem).